# SQL CASE return Dataset

Tags: sql, dataset, case

I just have a quick question.
Can you receive a set of data in a case statement
similar to:

```
CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN (SELECT name, age, gender FROM people) END
```

Comment: No.  Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish and then we can probably help?

Comment: Depends on the `CASE` being a control structure as some procedural extensions offer (PLpgSQL, though it should end with `END CASE` then) or not (No you cannot, if not the latter) and what you actually are trying to achieve here.

Comment: let's say that there is a html table, well depending on some variable value I have to populate the table with information from one of three sql tables, their fields are 90% the same but they do all have exclusive fields.  I am looking for a convenient way to conditionally get the data from each as I need it.  I hope this cleared the mud up a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with a `case` *expression* in a `select` *statement*.

A `case` expression is a scalar expression, so it can return only one value.

I should note that some databases support tuples.  In those databases, the values could be combined into a single tuple.